# Add HTML between div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
jQuery('.post-single-content').addClass('padT');            
jQuery('.post-single-content').css("padding-top", "40px");
```

It basically converts this:

```
<div class="post-single-content">
```

into this:

```
<div class="post-single-content padT" style="padding-top: 40px;">
```

I am however trying to change the code so it converts it into something like this:

```
<div class="post-single-content">
<a href="../index.html"><img src="../spacer.jpg"></a>
```

Could someone tell me how to do this. I've tried to use a few examples from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp) but had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/), llike this:

```
$('.post-single-content').append('<a href="../index.html"><img src="../spacer.jpg"></a>');
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/ZGzXyO)

Comment: Thank you! It work :). I ended up using .prepend instead of .append to get it to appear at the start of the div tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function after()

```
$(".post-single-content").after( '<a href="../index.html"><img src="../spacer.jpg"></a>' );
```

This solution adds the element after the .post-single-content div. You should use append():

```
$(".post-single-content").append( '<a href="../index.html"><img src="../spacer.jpg"></a>' );
```

Comment: This solution would add the new content after the div, and not inside in it.
You might want to use append instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may use jQuery to dynamically create new DOM objects and append them to an existing one:

```
var div = $('.post-single-content');
var link = $('a').attr('href', '../index.html');
var image = $('img').attr('src', '../spacer.jpg');
div.append(link.append(image));
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a single div you are trying to manipulate add an id.

```
<div id="divToChange" class="post-single-content padT" style="padding-top: 40px;"></div>
```

Then create the elements and append (a little more verbose than the other solutions, but never hurts to see a different way).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var targetDiv = $('#divToChange');

    var aTag = document.createElement('a');
    aTag.href = '../index.html';

    var imgTag = document.createElement('img');
    imgTag.src = '../spacer.jpg';

    $(imgTag).appendTo(aTag);
    $(aTag).appendTo(targetDiv);
});
```

Results in the following:

```
<div id="divToChange" class="post-single-content padT" style="padding-top: 40px;"><a href="../index.html"><img src="../spacer.jpg"></a></div>
```